# Using Plugins with KeePass2

Tags: 14.04, mono, keepass

I am trying to use the [GoogleSyncPlugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kp-googlesync/files/) with KeePass2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

After copying the GoogleSyncPlugin.plgx file to `/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins`, I run KeePass and I get this:

[image]

I have tried installing `mono-complete` and `mono --version` outputs this:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.1
```

Is there any way I can get this plugin to work?

Comment: @heynnema Mono is a .NET implementation on Linux. KeyPass is made in .NET and runs with mono itself.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the related Sourceforge thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/ab70a5b1/), "Due to the Google API SDK for .NET not playing nice with mono, the plugin will not work with Linux".

That was back in 2014, but I can't seem to find anything saying otherwise. All other Keepass2 plugins I use in Ubuntu have [Linux-specific PPA builds](https://launchpad.net/~dlech/+archive/ubuntu/keepass2-plugins), and GoogleSync isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks mate, do you have any alternative plugins that do the same thing as GoogleSync (push the keypass files to Google Drive?)

Comment: Not anything off the top of my head, sorry. I tend to use Dropbox or other methods for irregular transfers, since I don't update my personal DB that often. [Gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) or [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) might be worth poking your head into.